# How to call a function that is inherited from another contract using Hardhat?

Tags: solidity, remix, hardhat, testing, inheritance

I have deployed a smart contract that inherits `ERC721EnumerableUpgradeable` which inherits `ERC721Upgradeable`.

When I deploy using `Remix`, for example, I see the function `safeTransferFrom`, which is a function of the contract `ERC721Upgradeable`, despite I have just deployed my main contract, and all the methods that are public from inherited smart contracts are already there for me:

[image]

But when I use `Hardhat` and I want to test that same function, it seems that the `ERC721Upgradeable` contract is not being recognized, because I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: smartVault.safeTransferFrom is not a function
```

The test I am running is this one:

```
  it("Owner should be able to transfer smart NFT", async function () {
    const { smartVault, owner, otherAccount } = await loadFixture(deploySmartVault);
    await smartVault.safeTransferFrom(owner.address, otherAccount.address, 0);
  });
```

How can I get to interact with that function using `Hardhat`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that `safeTransferFrom` is a overloaded function. Overloaded functions are functions that are defined more than once, with the same name, but they take different types and/or number of arguments.

In `ethers.js` (which is the library that `Hardhat` uses under the hood), the syntax to call an overloaded contract function is different from the syntax to call a non-overloaded function.

Overloaded functions need to be called by specifying the function signature.

From the `ethers.js` docs:

```
// ethers
const abi = [
  "function getMessage(string) public view returns (string)",
  "function getMessage() public view returns (string)"
]
const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer);

// for ambiguous functions (two functions with the same
// name), the signature must also be specified
message = await contract['getMessage(string)']('nice');
```

So for the example in the question:

**Wrong**:

```
contract.safeTransferFrom(addr1, addr2, 1);
```

**Correct**:

```
contract["safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)"](addr1, addr2, 1);
```